# Wrap media query in class

Tags: css, media-queries

I was wondering if there as a reason why I couldn't wrap a media query I have for the home page with the .home{} class so that it only fires there.

So instead of

```css
@media (max-width:416px){
.home .et_pb_code_0 {
  border-right:0 !important;
 }
.home .et_pb_code_1 {
  border-right:0 !important;
 border-left:0 !important;
 }
 .home .et_pb_code_2 {
  border-left:0 !important;
 }
}
```

I would use:

```css
.home {
@media (max-width:416px){
 .et_pb_code_0 {
  border-right:0 !important;
 }
 .et_pb_code_1 {
  border-right:0 !important;
 border-left:0 !important;
 }
 .et_pb_code_2 {
  border-left:0 !important;
 }
}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Huh? So we're now creating our own syntax? I would like to write a condition using `if( a == b,c,d,e ) {}`

Comment: So your question essentially is, why can I not write stuff any way I like, but am bound to the specified syntax …? // CSS pre-processors like LESS or SASS allow you to write such constructs, and will compile them to proper CSS for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't work as it is not within the specification of css

Comment: Clearly if I'm asking this, then I don't know if this would be permissible under the Syntax guidelines. So rather than snippy comments, how about you answer the question? If it's a no then say no.

Comment: How about you read the css guidelines if you don't want snippy answers, after all you are meant to do research before posting a question

Comment: It's very much on topic as it's asking a question about CSS. How can that be off topic? If I was asking a question about Javascript and I put a CSS tag on the question then I could understand.

Comment: And posting in a forum to ask people who know more than me is not a way of doing research?

Comment: Nope, read the rules of SO

Comment: See now that's an answer I can get behind!

Comment: In answer to your post about forum rules, I've just checked the SO post guidelines and it doesn't say anything about asking a question without researching via other sites. It does however say that you should do some research on the site itself to see if your question has been asked before. I did this and that's why I asked the question as I couldn't see a similar one being asked.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 You show you did no research because you are asking to do the impossible. Your question would be more appropriate on amateur forums like reddit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, it's not the right syntax, may be you could use that with preprocesors like SASS and LESS, but not in pure CSS.

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question.